# how to import java code (using external jars) in jython?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jython-2.7

I am facing an issue while importing java code which uses some external jar say selenium_standalone_server jar.

I tried with normal code with no jars used in java, in this case i am able to import and run the code, but when i uses some jars in java code and then try to import that class to jython it gives error.

Here is the sample code i used. i created jar of the code below "jython_test.jar"

```
package Jython_workspace;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



public class selenium_try {

        public void launch_browser()
        {

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.out.println("Hello Google...");
            driver.get("http://google.com");

        }


}
```

this code uses the selenium_server-standalone-3.11.0.jar.

importing java jar in jython.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("jython_test.jar")

from jython_test import selenium_try as sel

beach = sel.launch_browser()
```

the error encountered.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PD\sublime_code\Jython_workspace\try_selenium_python.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jython_test import selenium_try as sel
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.loadAndInitClass(Py.java:991)
    at org.python.core.Py.findClassInternal(Py.java:926)
    at org.python.core.Py.findClassEx(Py.java:977)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:133)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.findClass(PackageManager.java:33)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:122)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:134)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:946)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1160)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1132)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(D:\PD\sublime_code\Jython_workspace\try_selenium_python.py:7)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(D:\PD\sublime_code\Jython_workspace\try_selenium_python.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:296)
    at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:362)
    at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:142)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader.findClass(SyspathJavaLoader.java:131)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

How this issue can be solved when java uses 3rd party jars and then we want to import in jython.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full package path when attempting to import Java classes.

Try using
`import Jython_workspace.selenium_try`.

Comment: i have updated the issue i am facing... could u have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer first we have to make method static used in java and import similar jar that have been imported in java to your jython code.
Thats all now you are good to go.